# Can't pull image from private registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment

I have this error (rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/registryName/projectName:latest": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html) when trying to deploy with the following deployment.yml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <projectName>-deployment
  namespace: <projectNamespace>
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <projectname>
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <projectName>
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: private-reg
        image: <registry>/<projectName>:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort:  9000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-hub-cred
```

I can't understand what's happening because using a simple pod.yml it's working:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: <projectName>-pod
  namespace: <projectNamespace>
spec:
  containers:
    - name: <projectName>
      image: <registry>/<projectName>:latest
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: docker-hub-cred
```

Comment: Try running the following `kubectl create deployment -n <namespace> <deployment-name> --image=<image> --port=<port> --dry-run=client -o yaml > deployment.yaml` 
edit the command accordingly and apply the newly created yaml

Comment: Sounds like a bad image. Can you provide a [mcve] (a public example we can inspect).

Comment: Both of you guys are right. After running kubectl create deployment ... and compose the ymls I notes that the image was missing one character. So last 4 hours was for that :). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.